# How to Type Half Up Arrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How can I type a half up arrow like in this figure:
[image: An Example]

Here, it means consider values of function f only on L(P).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By `\upharpoonrigh`.

Comment: \upharpoonright

Comment: Got it! Thanks! @Zarko

Comment: Got it! Thanks! @RaffaeleSantoro